# SVN server only allows commits when run as root

Tags: linux, svn, ubuntu, permissions

So as of two days ago, i had myself a shiny new SVN server. I set it up for WebDAV with no problems. It wasn't until i tried to host multiple projects that i ran into trouble.

At first, i had all of the project folders in one repository. But then i saw the error in my ways, and switched to multiple repositories. Rather than edit the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` file with every new project, i elected to use the svnserve deamon.

So, the problem is, i cn only make commits from Eclipse when the daemon is run as root. If not, I get a Permission Denied Error. Any ideas? Here are the directory stats:

```
    drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 2011-06-07 09:38 .
    drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 2011-06-05 00:48 ..
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 svn  svn     6 2011-06-06 22:35 all -> repos/
    drw-rw-r-- 6 svn  svn  4096 2011-06-06 13:53 EmpowerView
    drw-rw-r-- 6 svn  svn  4096 2011-06-06 13:54 GoogleVoicemail
    -rw-rw-r-- 2 svn  svn   307 2011-06-07 08:47 passwd
    drw-rw-r-- 6 svn  svn  4096 2011-06-06 13:54 PerlinNoise
    drw-rw-r-- 7 svn  svn  4096 2011-06-05 02:15 repos
    -rw-rw-r-- 3 svn  svn  2278 2011-06-07 08:46 svnserve.conf
```

## EDIT

I tried the suggested re-checkout with the daemon not running as root, and still no cigar. Same permission error.

## EDIT 2

I also tried running the daemon as the user svn, but no such luck. At one point I screwed up my primary group and no longer had sudo privileges! I had to hack into my own server through a buddy's account

## EDIT 3 *ANSWER*

Well, after a few hours of tinkering, here is the setup that i got to work.

First I deleted any existing checkouts, and killed the deamon.
Then I set all the permissions to 774 for all my repositories (see below)
Next, I ran the daemon with this command sudo -u svn -- svnserve -d -r /storage/svn/
This allowed me to run the deamon as the user 'svn' without entering a password. (svn has no password or shell for security reasons)
Finally, I double checked all my config files, and was able to do checkouts exactly as hoped.
Repositories Directory

```
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 2011-06-07 10:34 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 2011-06-05 00:48 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 svn  svn     6 2011-06-06 22:35 all -> repos/
drwxrwxr-- 6 svn  svn  4096 2011-06-06 13:53 EmpowerView
drwxrwxr-- 6 svn  svn  4096 2011-06-06 13:54 GoogleVoicemail
-rwxrwxr-- 2 svn  svn   307 2011-06-07 08:47 passwd
drwxrwxr-- 6 svn  svn  4096 2011-06-06 13:54 PerlinNoise
drwxrwxr-- 7 svn  svn  4096 2011-06-05 02:15 repos
-rwxrwxr-- 3 svn  svn  2273 2011-06-07 09:50 svnserve.conf
```

(Note: All of my repositories share common editors and permissions, so in each repositories conf/ folder, i put hardlinks to the passwd and svnserve.conf files above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the svn daemon has read permission to your repository but not write permission.

First find out under what user the svn daemon runs. Then chown the full repository to that user. That way the daemon can write your commits also.

Answer (score 1):

Weird things happen when you commit, or checkout as root. Try to checkout a given repository not as root, and if that works you should be able to commit to it as a regular user thereafter.

If that still doesn't work, check the permissions on the repository itself. It's possible that the permissions aren't set in order to allow non-root users commit access.

Comment: I've posted the permissions. The repository in question is the EmpowerView listed above.

Comment: Also, i wasn't checking out as root, but only running the daemon as root. Is that what you were referring to?

Comment: And you can't commit/check out as the "svn" user, per the permissions listed? Hm.

Running the daemon as root gives root privileges to everything the daemon does.

Comment: The only reason i ask is because i heard that running the daemon as root wasn't "kosher" (Good practice) Is that correct?

Comment: Ah, well I would say yes, that's correct. You want to establish permissions to your repositories such that they can be worked on without root privileges. In *nix in general, you don't want to run things as root. The reasons for this are numerous, and not necessarily obvious (why wouldn't you want to use the account that as unrestricted access, after all?), but you should avoid using root for things that don't require it.

Comment: How could I run the daemon as the svn user? Svn has no password nor does it have a shell.

Comment: You can grant those privileges to the svn user. I don't want to get too deep into your particular implementation - if you give svn a password, and shell access, but it still doesn't work you may need to just roll with what you're doing. :( If none of that works, I can remove my answer if you prefer.

Comment: All your help actually did lead me to an answer, so i will definitely upvote it. Thank you!